# Does Arduino's .toCharArray() method have a bug?

Tags: arrays, string, arduino

Suppose I have a string "AB", that I want to convert to a char[] array and 
print the two char array elements in HEX to the serial monitor. Should be quite simple. However, the second element always prints as 0.

```
String line = "AB";
Serial.println();
Serial.print(line);
Serial.println();
char myarray[2];
line.toCharArray(myarray,2);
Serial.print(myarray[0],HEX);
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print(myarray[1],HEX);
Serial.print(' ');
```

The output I am getting is

```
AB
41 0
```

Comment: Try `char myarray[3];` and `line.toCharArray(myarray,3);`

Comment: With this approach, the last element of the array is still a 0. Basically, for my application I need the last element of the array to be the last character of the string. I know I can use this workaround or other ones, but I want to know why is the toCharArray() method not working as it should?

Comment: It looks like it is zero terminator. This is how c-strings work

Comment: The `toCharArray` method is working as it should. Strings in C are arrays of characters where the last character is the NUL terminator. So the string `"AB"` is not 2 characters, it's  `'A', 'B', '\0'` which is 3 characters.

Comment: Does anyone have editing access to the documentation describing this method https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray? This critical information should definitely be there to save people from hours of frustration.

Comment: The documentation is pretty fine. *len: the size of the _buffer_* The buffer contains the characters itself and the `NUL` terminator. Developing in C one should know how strings work and there is no reason to repeat that in every  function doc. (Docs should and do mention, if there is the chance to get a result, that is not `NUL`terminated.)

Comment: Arduino is definitively not C! And not exactly C++.

Answer (score 2):

`toCharArray` will copy as many characters into the buffer as it can ***while still returning a valid C string***. A valid C string has a nul (00) terminating byte. If you give it a 2 byte buffer, it can fit only one character before the nul terminator.

(Look at the Arduino source where it calculates how many characters to copy. https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp#L544 The `bufsize - 1` is where it is leaving room for a nul terminator.)

Your code should be

`char myarray[3]; // Make room for 2 chars + nul terminator
line.toCharArray(myarray, sizeof(myarray)); // Use sizeof to avoid repeating '2'`

But really, you don't need a buffer to copy into at all. String already has a character accessor, `charAt()`

`Serial.print(line.charAt(0), HEX);
Serial.print(line.charAt(1), HEX);`